# How to plot a 3D scatter plot with color code in the z direction in Python

Tags: python

I have a collection of data points. The x, y, and z axis have different lengths. I want to plot a 3D scatter plot with color code which changes as the value of the plotted function varies in z direction.

Comment: This question would be clearer if you posted some example data or some code that generates the data you want to plot.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming an image is what your going for:

A few googles quickly turn up a some python plotting libraries. One option would be to use [matplotlib](http://matplotlib.org/). From what I can get from your question you can use [Axes3D.scatter](http://matplotlib.org/mpl_toolkits/mplot3d/tutorial.html?highlight=scatter#mpl_toolkits.mplot3d.Axes3D.scatter) and programmatically create an array of colors depending on the z value of your plot points and use this as the 'c' parameter.
[image]
This might not scale depending on how many data points you need to plot, but I'm guessing we're not talking about millions of data points here, in which case you should be fine with this method...

Comment: Sorry if I did something wrong. I tried to answer his question as best I could with the limited information given in the second part of my post. Indeed I also pointed out that we could do with some more information. Should I have just put the answer section in my answer and then comment on my own answer with the request for more information?